# Copy and Pasting a row based on a condition

Tags: excel, vba

Copy and Pasting an entire row based off of two conditions

For a school project, I am trying to find all the rows that satisfy both (of two) conditions then paste the entire row at the end of my data set. I am trying to do this with variables as the spreadsheet may change in tests that my professor will perform. I keep getting a "Subscript out of range" error. My reading and assigning to P and T, for loop, if statements, and count functions all work.

```
numrow = Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
numcolumn = Columns(Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column
P = Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(numrow, 1)).Value
T = Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(numrow, 2)).Value

For i = LBound(P, 1) To UBound(P, 1)
    If P(i, 1) = 5 And T(i, 1) = 100 Then
       countrow = countrow + 1 'check: return is 25

       'Range(i, numcolumn).copy Sheets("Sheet1").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, numcolumn)).Value.copy
        lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
        Range(Cells(lastrow, 1)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
'I would also like to change all the cells that were just pasted in the first column to the value of 2.5 here, but I have no idea where to start with that
    End If
Next i
```

As you can see I tried it two ways
1.)
Range(i, numcolumn).copy Sheets("Sheet1").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
(which is commented for now)
2.)
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, numcolumn)).Value.copy

both get highlighted when I try to debug and have the "subscript out of range" error

Comment: Do you have a sheet named "Sheet1"? Also, I'm not sure you want `Columns(Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column`. That would be the rightmost column of the sheet - e.g. 16384. Maybe you're looking for `xlToLeft`.

Comment: Also you can't do `Range.Value.Copy`.

Comment: Yes I have a worksheet named Sheet1, could I do: Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, numcolumn)).Select.... then say Select.Copy?